# Spring multi-tenancy: context per tenant

Tags: java, spring, multi-tenant, thread-local

I've got a Spring webapp that is of a multi-tenant design, through use of ThreadLocal. There's a single spring context that all tenants use and they share the same configuration classes and beans.

Due to some extra requirements, I want to allow each tenant to have their own context so that they can override beans.

The tenants configs are decided by a URL pattern.

I'm not that familiar with multi-tenancy and wondered what people's ideas of the best approach to this is.